# Why will this JOptionPane command not work?

Tags: java

Why does this JOptionPane command not work?

```
  if (let != 'D' || let != 'S' || let != 'M' || let != 'A' || let != 'X'){
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Wrong character entered.", 
  JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);}
```

It seems to give me the error message:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Wrong character entered.", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);}
             ^
method JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Component,Object,String,int,Icon) is not applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Component,Object,String,int) is not applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Component,Object) is not applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to call a method by passing wrong arguments. There is no method like `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Component parentComponent,String message,int messageType`).

May be you are looking for this method. [`JOptionPane#showMessageDialog(Component parentComponent, Object message, String title, int messageType)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int)).
You can pass any `String` as a title of `DialogBox`.

So change

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Wrong character entered.", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

to

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Wrong character entered.", "Attention!" ,JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `title` argument. It should be passed immediately after the message:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, 
                               "Wrong character entered.", 
                               "Title", 
                               JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

For more info on this method: visit [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-int-).